# Как перехватить сообщение о выключении компа?

Tags: delphi

Когда комп выключается, винда посылает сообщение всем программам. Как мне это сообщение перехватить и допустим отменить или заменить? В какую сторону копать? Help me!

Answer (score 2):

Начните с [этого](http://delphiworld.narod.ru/base/win_shutdown_detect.html) и [этого](http://www.sql.ru/forum/113893/kak-pravilno-obrabotat-soobshhenie-wm-queryendsession).

И в [нагрузку](http://www.codeguru.com.ua/article/a-460.html).